# Solving a system of simultaneous equations with modified multiplication rules

Tags: equation-solving

Hello and thanks in advance for your help.  Is there a way to solve a system of simultaneous equations in Mathematica where because of the nature of the system being modeled, the rules for multiplying variables is non-standard such that during algebraic manipulation, a variable $x_i^n$ is always equal to $x_i$.  For example under these modified multiplication rules, $5x^2y^9z^7$ would simplify to $5xyz$.

It is known that solutions to the system always result in variable values equal to or greater than zero, and thus odd power exponents will never change the sign of a term.  The equations in the system are all polynomials where variables are of the first power, with terms that may include any number or combination of system variables and one constant and only involve multiplication.  One of the terms in an equation may be a constant.  Each polynomial is always equal to zero.  For example if there are ten variables and ten equations, one of the polynomial example terms could be $3x_3x_4$ or $7x_1x_5x_8x_9$ or in a more extreme example, $5x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8x_9$.

Thanks in advance for any help.  Inherent in this question is whether it is possible in Mathematica to change the rules by which a basic operator functions, in this case the multiplication operator.  Also, what is the best Mathematica function to use in solving a system of equations of this kind, putting aside the unusual multiplication situation?  Thanks again for any help.

Comment: (1) Please add a minimal example of a system you with to solve. (2) You can explicitly add the equations `x[j]^2==x[j]`, but this will force all variable solution values to be 0 or 1. Which is appropriate, in the setting of Boolean algebras. But it is not clear that this is what is wanted.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];

Format[x[n_]] = Subscript[x, n];

Format[y[n_]] = Subscript[y, n];

vars = Join[Array[x, 3], Array[y, 2]];
```

Use [`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html) to change powers

```
$Post = # /. {x[j_]^m_ :> x[j], y[k_]^n_ :> y[k]} &;

poly = (7 + Total[vars])^3 // Expand
```

[image]

```
poly // Simplify
```

[image]

```
(% // Expand) === poly

(* True *)
```

To restore `$Post`to its default

```
$Post =.
```